# ¿Qué significa "src name"? ¿Como puedo solucionar el siguiente error?

Tags: java, android, json, url

1_Estoy tratando de descargar una imagen a partir de la siguiente URL: "http://10.1.1.2:8080/basket.png". Y estuve tratando de hacerlo mediante un elemento de tipo Drawable a partir de lo que [dice el siguiente link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android). El problema que tengo es que no entiendo a que se refiere cuando dice "src name"...Ahi que deberia escribir en mi caso?

2_ La url la obtengo a partir de un objeto JSON proveniente del servidor (el cual funciona correctamente el hecho de traerlo ya que el mismo fue testeado) y me tira el siguiente error cuando bajo la imagen (escribiendo directamente "src name"): `Value java.net.ConnectException of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

El codigo el cual solicita la imagen es el siguiente:

```
protected Drawable getDrawable()
    {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
            String src=jsonResponse.getString(data);
            InputStream is = (InputStream)new URL(src).getContent();
            Drawable d=Drawable.createFromStream(is, "basket.png");
            return d;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            String err="este es el error:";
            Log.e(err,e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

El codigo que se encarga de mostrar el resultado por pantalla es el siguiente:

```
public class Accedido extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imagen;
    Button ok;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accedido);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Img);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Drawable img=null;
                Ajax im=new Ajax();
                try {
                    String imagen = im.execute(MainActivity.IP_ADDRESS + "Imagen").get();
                    LeerConsulta lec = new LeerConsulta(imagen, "img");
                    //img=lec.getBitMap();
                    /*String res=lec.getContent();
                    String res2=lec.getData();
                    Toast.makeText(Accedido.this, "Content:"+res+"Data:"+res2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                    img=lec.getDrawable();
                }
                catch(Exception exc) {
                    Toast.makeText(Accedido.this, exc.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                imagen.setImageDrawable(img);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

En realidad en lugar de "src name" debes asignar un nombre de imagen el cual contendrà la imagen, por ejeplo:

```
Drawable.createFromStream(is, "imagen.jpg");
```

---

En cuanto a tu error

> Value java.net.ConnectException of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject

Significa que el valor de `content` no es un json por esa razón no puede ser convertido a JsonObject.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
```

---

Para que funcione todo correctamente, debes procurar varias cosas

La variable `content` debe tener un objeto json:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
```

La variable `data` debe contener la llave (`key`) la cual tiene como valor el url de la imagen, ya que por medio de la key se obtiene el url de la imagen y se asigna ala variable `src`

`String src = jsonResponse.getString(data);`

Al obtener la ruta de la imagen creamos un `InputStream`.

```
InputStream is = (InputStream)new URL(src).getContent();
```

Y al final al obtener un `InputStream` creamos un `Drawable` que sería la imagen:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "myimagen.jpg");
```

Comment: La imagen que quiero obtener se llama basket.png, por lo que puse eso en el string. Recien hice una prueba y, lo que recibe en content es `{"img":"http://10.1.1.2:8080/basket.png"}`. Y en data se encuentra el valor `img`

Comment: Ok entonces data debe tener el valor de "img". Es así?

Comment: Asi es Elenasys (obviamente, es una cadena la cual el valor mismo no tiene las comillas). Ante cualquier duda, puse el codigo como esta ahora (poniendo basket.png en lugar de "src name")

Comment: Ok ya probaste nuevamente? :)

Comment: Probe y no funciono :(. Cuando lo pruebo me sale la siguiente excepcion tambien en el celular: `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`. Agregue la parte del codigo en donde se muestra la imagen por las dudas

Comment: Ese es otro error que no tiene que ver con esto, tienes en algún lugar System.out.prinln() ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51495/discussion-between-f-riggio-and-elenasys).